# A Component not rendering in react-native in App.js. Please correct me.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying a simple react-native. My codes are:

My App.js file is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Headers from './Header';
import Deck from './Deck';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

const DATA = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Card #1', uri: 'http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/paul0v2/unsplash/unsplash-04.jpg' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Card #2', uri: 'http://www.fluxdigital.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Unsplash.jpg' },
  { id: 3, text: 'Card #3', uri: 'http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/paul0v2/unsplash/unsplash-09.jpg' },
  { id: 4, text: 'Card #4', uri: 'http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/paul0v2/unsplash/unsplash-01.jpg' },
  { id: 5, text: 'Card #5', uri: 'http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/paul0v2/unsplash/unsplash-04.jpg' },
  { id: 6, text: 'Card #6', uri: 'http://www.fluxdigital.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Unsplash.jpg' },
  { id: 7, text: 'Card #7', uri: 'http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/paul0v2/unsplash/unsplash-09.jpg' },
  { id: 8, text: 'Card #8', uri: 'http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/paul0v2/unsplash/unsplash-01.jpg' },
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  renderCard(item){
    console.log("item=",item)
      return(
        <Card
          key={item.id}
          title={item.text}
          image={{uri: item.uri}}
        >
          <Button 
            icon={{ name: 'code'}}
            backgroundColor="#123abc"
            title="View Now"
          />
        </Card>
      );
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>123</Text>
        <Deck
          data={DATA}
          renderCard={this.renderCard}
        />
        <Text>234</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and my Deck.js is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Animated, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
export default class Deck extends Component {
  renderCards(){
    return this.props.data.map(item=>{
        this.props.renderCard(item)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
      {this.renderCards()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As I console in App.js, the item required are shown in console, but the card  component is not rendering as expected. I wonder what mistake have I done here.

Please go through the code once and correct where the mistake has been done.

Answer (score 1):

When using Array.map, you need to return something through each iteration, or else, your resulting array will be empty and nothing will be rendered. Your Deck.js should be like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Animated, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Deck extends Component {
  renderCards(){
    return this.props.data.map(item => {
        return this.props.renderCard(item);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.renderCards()}
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```